# How to reduce the memory usage of the Cobalt

Tags: cobalt

We want to use the Cobalt to run YouTube application on our STB with only 256M in memory. Whether YouTube application supports 720P resolution or reduces application specifications, such as reducing image resolution, removing animation effects, etc., to reduce the use of cobalt memory.Could we reduce the use of Cobalt memory in the way of YouTube application?
Thanks!

Comment: Cobalt is known to run YouTube on devices with 256MB of RAM. Please contact your YouTube account manager about possibility to run YouTube on your device.

Answer (score 0):

For information on memory tuning see https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/doc/memory_tuning.md.